# How can I have vertical scroll bar for table in GSP?

Tags: html, css-tables

I have table in my gsp. And I want to have vertical scroll bar to it. How can I do that.

Comment: this question is more related to html/css than gsp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not with TABLE Element, You do can with DIV

```
<div style="overflow: scroll/auto/hidden;"></div>
```

scroll always prints both the vertical and the horizontal scroll-bars
auto makes one or the others or both to appear as soon as content grows;
hidden always prevent both scroll-bars from appearing.

DIV can either contain a TABLE (as code below) and be contained in a TD table-cell.
If DIV inside a table at whichsoever level of the document, HEIGHT You want to assign to a  gets fooled if given in % percentage; still works fine in pixel, instead.

So you just need to include your table element inside the div with :

```
style='overflow:scroll'
```

Comment: I did it as u..i have added above <div> with style='overflow:scroll'.but its not working why so

Comment: with out auto/hidden i am getting scroll bar but both vertical and horizontal bar's are disabled.and when i give scroll/auto/hidden scroll bar only not displaying.

Comment: When i give scroll/auto one of the scroll should activate know.but why is'nt its working

Comment: hey now my other problem with scrolling is that i don want my first row of table which has headings for fields to be scrolled.how to prevent that